# How to link ASP Asynchronous Postback with jQuery function

Tags: jquery, asp.net, partial-postback

So I have a page with an < asp:UpdatePanel > every time that UpdatePanel updates my jQuery function is thrown out.

Right now I'm making sure the function fires when a user mouses over (.mouseenter) that DIV. Is there a way to make the function fire when an update happens?

I've tried .change, .ready, and .load but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create a script manager proxy on that page.  Then - in the code-behind, register a "start-up" script that will fire each time the update panel refreshes.

In your markup, add the proxy for the script manager:

```
<asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="scriptManagerProxy1" runat="server" />
```

Then, in your code behind, initiate the event:

```
 Private Sub scriptManagerProxy1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles scriptManagerProxy1.Load
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Me.Page.GetType(), Me.Page.UniqueID, "FunctionToCall();", True)
    End Sub
```

You may not need the proxy if you have the script manager on the same page/control - in which case you could probably use the load event of the script manager itself.